# insert item to list without insert() or append() Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to work on a function for an assignment and I'm new to coding. Part of it is to make user insert item to list by entering the desired item and the index without the built-in functions. Currently, I've got the code to replace the item in that index but I can't get it to do what it's supposed to.

Object is the item, and the list is in the main function.

```
def add(list, obj, index):
    nlist = []
    print("Your list ", list)
    item = input("Insert item: ")
    index = int(input("Index: "))
    i = 0
    for e in list:
        if i < index:
            nlist.append(e)
            i += 1
        elif i == index:
            nlist.append(obj)
            i += 1
        elif i > index:
            nlist.append(e)
            i += 1
    print("Your new list ", nlist)
```

Comment: how about `nlist+[e]`

Comment: It looks like you get the the object and the index passed as arguments, so you probably shouldnt use `input` here.

Comment: Seriously, you can't use `append`? That will force you to use some other, less efficient method that doesn't really add to understanding at all.

Comment: you could concat the list into `[:index]` + desired item + `[index:]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Unless it's a contrived exercise to teach slicing. Which is still a terrible assignment, but if you're trying to get them to use slicing...

Comment: if you can return a new list `list[:index] + [obj] + list[index:]`

Comment: @Eular It works until I add the new item to the end of the list, which duplicates the value of the index before that instead of inserting the new item.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Imagine you have one of those magnetic train sets. like [image]

You want to add a train car after the second one. So you'd break apart the train between index `1` and `2` and then attach it. The front part is everything from 0 to 1 and the second part is everything from 2 till the end.

Luckily, python has a really nice slice syntax: `x[i:j]` means slice from `i` (inclusive) to `j` (exclusive). `x[:j]` means slice from the front till `j` and `x[i:]` means slice from `i` till the end.

So we can do

```
def add(lst, obj, index): return lst[:index] + [obj] + lst[index:]
```

Comment: If you are allowed to mutate the list, `lst[x:x] = [obj]` inserts `obj` just prior to element `x`. `x = 0` lets you prepend, and `lst[-1:]` (the exception) appends.

Comment: @chepner Doing `lst[-1:] = [obj]` will replace the last element with `obj` rather than appending it... On the other hand, `lst[len(lst):] = [obj]` will append

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
idx = 3
value=[7]

def insert_gen(a,idx,value):
    b=a[:idx] + value + a[idx:]
    return b

final = insert_gen(a,idx,value)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace an empty slice with a list containing the object:

```
lst[index:index] = [obj]
```

Demo:

```
>>> for index in range(4):
        lst = [0, 1, 2]
        lst[index:index] = [9]
        print(lst)
    
[9, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 9, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 9, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 9]
```